# HTML coding for Facebook Like Box on personal Website

Tags: html, facebook-likebox

My software I use to create my webpage - IWEB (on Macbook PRO) doesn't support HTML5 coding that you use for the Facebook LIKEBOX.  It is a drag & drop program whereby you can drag a HTML 'snippet' box which you copy & paste the coding into.  (I don't write code)

I have had an older HTML code in there & only yesterday I tried to update with the new code & realized it's HTML5.

I have tried various codes from the internet one displays the box correctly within the program.... but when I publish the page nothing can be seen on the website.

Apologies if I am being vague, or not using 'code speak' - I am not a programmer.
Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [the old HTML coding for Like Box](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7935294/the-old-html-coding-for-like-box)

Comment: What is your question, Corey?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the HTML5 version, the generator at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ has options for

- HTML5, which should work OK for most browsers
- XFBML (which uses the Javascript API - the generator code will give you the code to include this too, so it should be a simple copy/paste)
- iframe (which is only applicable if you don't have the 'send' button option enabled)

All of these can be chosen from the top line of the dialog that appears on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/